# DST Root CA X3 Expiration Sep 30 - Is there any way to make old devices work still?

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

TLDR: There was a recent DST Root CA X3 Expiration - is there any way to update something on my server that makes old devices trust it again?

All - I am so very very lost on this and don't know where to turn. I have a few hundred linux signage players out in customer's stores that are refusing to connect to my server since Sep 30/21 due to the DST Root CA expiration.

From my understanding, this issue is caused by a certificate on the old devices, even though SSL is valid on my server, it does not trust the server? I am getting error: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired.

 
The signage players work when I run a software update which replaces the certificate but it will cost thousands to go out and manually run software updates. Is there anything I can do short term such as use a different SSL provider to make these old devices trust my server again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is on-topic. Based on my understanding of your question and the expired DST root cert problem, there are two related problems: 1) server using expired certs in its chain and 2) the new ISRG root certificate is not trusted on old devices. The first one is easy to solve, just update your server certificate. The second one is the hard one.

Since you are concerned with cost, here is a suggestion. First, find out which root certificates your remote devices trust. From this list, find root certificates that don't expire until a date in the future that you're comfortable with. Then **buy** a certificate from one of the CAs that own one of the roots whose expiration date you're comfortable with. Costs vary, but I would expect the cost is at most in the low hundreds per year, possibly much less depending on the CA.

Longer term, if you ever get out to update the boxes, you might want to reconsider your PKI model. If it's just your devices connecting to your server it might be wiser to use your own home grown CA certificate with a long expiration date to issue your certificates for this application.